# Bootstrap does not work as it should on my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a two column layout. The first side should span 9 columns and the next one 3. Inside the col-md-9 I want to nest two more columns, one that spans 4 and another one that spans 8.

```
 <div class="row">
  <% @huddles.each do |huddle| %>
   <div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <h4><%= huddle.title %></h4>
       <h4 class="huddle-description"><%= huddle.description %></h4>
       <%= link_to "Read More...", huddle_path(huddle) %>
      </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">Second Column</div>
</div>
```

This however, comes out looking like this:

[image]

Am I nesting my rows and columns wrong? Or maybe it is my ruby code itself that screws up the layout once new "Huddles" are created?

**EDIT**: With the fixed code, the second column "col-md-3" comes out next to the last created huddle. Inspecting it, all the huddles make one single row.

```
<div class="row">
 <% @huddles.each do |huddle| %>
  <div class="col-md-9">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4><%= huddle.title %></h4>
     <h4 class="huddle-description"><%= huddle.description %></h4>
     <%= link_to "Read More...", huddle_path(huddle) %>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 <div class="col-md-3">Second Column</div>
</div>
```

And looks like this, where the second column moves all the way down next to the last huddle created:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are going for. I am pretty confident the issue is with the html structure and has nothing to do with ruby.

I also want to clarify.  The initial issue you were having was that you were starting a div inside the loop but only closing it outside the loop.  So starting n amount of divs but only one closing tag, and that would cause it to look like the image you first posted.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">
  <% @huddles.each do |huddle| %>
    <div class="show-region" >
      <div class="col-md-4"  style="height:150px;">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8"  style="height:150px;">
       <h4><%= huddle.title %></h4>
       <h4 class="huddle-description"><%= huddle.description %></h4>
       <%= link_to "Read More...", subjects_path(huddle) %>
      </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Second Column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost, the Second Column should only be one, not repeat every time with each huddle, but stay parallel with col-md-9.
Like if I move the <%end %> before it, Second Column just appears once, but right next to the last huddle. I want it to start next to the first huddle, and be able to add more content underneath it.

Comment: thanks, but "Second Column" sticks next to the last huddle created, it should start at the top with the row.

Comment: is it next to it, or underneath?  What I mean is the col-md-9 pushing it out of the way due to padding or something? Does the class "show-region" have any padding or margin?

Comment: No, that's an old style, I just noticed, but has no attributes. 
I updated my question with an image.

Comment: You are going to run into issues if the height of the boxes is different.  If you set a height the layout will work, without it the current structure will cascade and not look correct.  You may need to look at a solution to make sure that the height of the boxes for the md-8 and md-4 are always the same.  The updated solution should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it!